# jquery check json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using the google news search api and get back data in json format. I am using ajax to get the data and parse through it.

This is my code:

```
function doAjax(query){
    alert(query);
    var target = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q="+query+"&rsz=large";
    $.ajax({
        url: target,
        cache: false,                   
        dataType:'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data.responseData.results);
            for(var x = 0; x < 8; x++){
                var title = data.responseData.results[x].titleNoFormatting;
                //var content = data.responseData.results[x].content;
                //var image = data.responseData.results[x].image.url;

                $("#home").append(x+"---"+title+'<hr>');
            }
        },
        error: function(jxhr,e){
        alert(jxhr.status+" --- "+e.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

When I run the code this way I get 8 titles. but when I uncomment this line `var image = data.responseData.results[x].image.url;` I get 3 or 4 results only. I investigated the data being retrieved from google I found that some results has no images. How can I check the json result if it has an image. I still want to display the title of the article even if there was no image.

Comment: image = data.responseData.results[x].image && data.responseData.results[x].image.url

Comment: var image= data.responseData.results[x].image; image= image && image.url;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check the image exists before get it's url

```
if(typeof(data.responseData.results[x].image) == "undefined"){
    alert('no image');
}else{
    var image = data.responseData.results[x].image.url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What does the response look like? Most browsers have developer tools that will let you see the requests and response. Likely, your loop is choking because `data.responseData.results[x].image` is undefined so `data.responseData.result[x].image.url` throws a type error (undefined doesn't have a `url` property).

To guard against this, just check for it like this:

```
if(data.responseData.result[x].image) {
    var image = data.responseData.result[x].image.url;
}
```

If `data.responseData.result[x].image` is `undefined` then it will evaluate as falsey and the body of the `if` won't be executed (and won't throw an error that breaks you out of the function).

Answer (score 1):

You can check for image like

```
if (typeof data.responseData.image != 'undefined' && typeof data.responseData.image.url != 'undefined' ) {
    // set the image here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Typeof](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp) can be used to determine if a variable is defined or not.

Example

```
var var_one = "";

alert(typeof var_one); // alerts "string"
alert(typeof var_two); // alerts "undefined"
alert(typeof var_two == "undefined"); // alerts "true"
```

So you can specify:

```
if (typeof var_two != "undefined")
{
    alert("variable is undefined!");
}
else
{
    alert("variable is defined... use it!");
}
```

Taking the above into account, you could do:

```
var image = "";

if (typeof data.responseData.results[x].image.url != "undefined")
{
    image = data.responseData.results[x].image.url;

    // You can then specify where the image url will go.
}
```